# How to add a ejs if statement when user follows a user a unfollow button will be shown vice-versa

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs, mongoose-schema

I have this route for followed users. By using req.params.id, everything works well and was able to push the requested user id to the user.

the problem now is in my EJS where if a user is followed and a unfollow button appear but follow button is still shown. Is there any way that if i unfollow a user the follow button will be shown?

this is my code

```
router.get('/follow/:id', isLoggedIn, async function(req, res) {
try {
let user = await User.findById(req.params.id)
if(req.user.id ===  req.params.id) {
req.flash('error', 'You cannot add yourself') 
res.redirect('back')
} else {
 user.followers.addToSet({_id: req.user._id} );
 user.save();

 req.flash('success', 'Successfully followed ' + user.local.username + 
'!');
  res.redirect('back');
}   

} catch(err) {
req.flash('error','Author is already added');
res.redirect('back');
}
});

router.delete('/follow/:id', isLoggedIn, async function(req, res) {
try {


let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id);

  user.followers.pull(req.user.id);
  user.save();
  req.flash('success', 'Successfully unfollowed ' + user.local.username + 
'!');
  res.redirect('back');

 } catch(err) {
req.flash('error', err.message);
res.redirect('back');
 }
```

});

user schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Service = require('../models/services')
const Review = require('../models/review')

// Create a schema
const userSchema = new Schema({

local: {
email: {
  type: String,
  lowercase: true,
  unique: true,
},
password: { 
  type: String,
  require: true
},

notifications: [
{
 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: 'Notification'
 }
],

followers: [
{
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'User', 
}
],
```

Profile .ejs

```
<% layout('./layouts/boilerplate') -%>



<div class="container-fluid profilecard">
    <div class="profile-card">
            <div class="image-container">
            <div class="img-thumbnail">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="<%= user.local.images.url %>" 
style= "width: 100%;">
            </div>
 <div class="title">
  <p><h2 class="text-center"> <%=user.local.username %> 
<%=user.facebook.name %></h2></p> 
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="follow justify-content-center">
 <a href="/users/follow/<%= user.id %>"><button class="btn btn- 
primary">Follow <%= user.local.username %></button></a>
     <% user.followers.forEach(function(follower){ %>
       <% if(currentUser && 
currentUser._id.equals(follower.id)) {%>
   <form id="delete-btn" action="/users/follow/<%= user.id%>? 
_method=DELETE" method="POST">
  <button class="btn btn- 
 danger">Unfollow</button>
   </form>
    <% }  %>   
  <% }) %>
  </div>
```

i tried to add else <%=currentUser._id !== follower._id it doesn't work

Need some advice here

Answer (score 0):

I have done this myself on the profile-page and it seems to work great. In the route to show the profile-page i populate followers by doing this:

```
User.findById(req.params.id).populate("followers").exec(function(err, foundUser)
```

After that in my template i am looping through the followers list to check if there is an id match. If there is an id the boolean is changed.

```
<% var isFollowing = false;
user.followers.forEach(function(follower) {
    if(currentUser && follower._id.equals(currentUser._id)) {
        isFollowing = true;
        return false;
    } 
}); 
if( isFollowing ) { %>
    <div class="Button-Collection">
    <a href="/profile/<%= user.id %>/unfollow" class="Button Remove" title="Follow <%= user.firstName %>">Unfollow</a>
    </div>
<% } else { %>
    <div class="Button-Collection">
    <a href="/profile/<%= user.id %>/follow" class="Button Add" title="Follow <%= user.firstName %>">Follow</a>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Hope this is going to work for you :-)